# How to find deleted list items in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-item

We have a list with few hundreds of records in it. There are some list items that are deleted in past. We need to get the list of items (title of the list items) that have been deleted so far. These items are no longer present in recycle bin.

I've seen this post: [How to find when a SharePoint list item was deleted?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16705/how-to-find-when-a-sharepoint-list-item-was-deleted)

Here it is mentioned that we should enable audit logs. But this will tell us about the items that will be deleted after we enable it. But is there any way to get the items that have been deleted in past, long time back?

I tried check the AllUserData table in DB. But it seems that SharePoint deletes the list items from this table as well. Is there any other place from where I can get the list of deleted items?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out which items were deleted prior to this day, and auditing is not enabled for that list, there is no way. Those items are completely gone. Even in SharePoint's ChangeLog all you will find is that an item *was* deleted at some point, but no indication which (other than its ID).

Turn on basic auditing (beware database usage), or implement some other form of custom logging mechanism for the future. In every corporation I've seen, there always seems to be someone who eventually thinks it's suddenly very important to surface events which were never logged in the first place.